# DOJO ContentPane inner DIV height changing on ContentPane resize

Tags: layout, dojo, dijit.layout, contentpane

I'm using DOJO's `ContentPane` module. I have a `div` element in one of the panes and I need to give it a certain height - 100 pixels less than the height of the `ContentPane` so that the `div` changes its height dynamically when you change the `ContentPane` size by dragging the splitters. I'm new to Dojo and would be happy if somebody could help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is via nested `BorderContainers` with properly set `splitters`, because that way `dijit/layout` will take care of resizing and you won't need to write any JavaScript code and your layout will be based solely on CSS.

It's kinda cumbersome to explain, so I created a working example for you at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/Ayg8F/ + a diagram:

[image]

NB: Do not forget to set `height: 100%` for `html`, `body` and the top `BorderContainer`.

The drawback of this solution is you will have to replace plain `divs` with `ContentPanes`. If you do not want to or can't you can use `dojo/aspect` and connect to `BorderContainer` or `ContentPane` `resize` method and resize your `divs` manually whenever the size changes:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
], function(
    ready,
    aspect,
    registry
) {

    ready(function() {
        var bc = registry.byId("borderContainer1");
        aspect.after(bc, "resize", function() {
            // calculate and set <div> size here
            console.log("resize divs");
        });
    });  
});​
```